# netlogo - Random forward -

Tags: netlogo

my code is:

```
to move  
  rt random 100
  lt random 100
  fd 20

  set energy energy - 0.5
end
```

I want to set fd between two values or maybe greater and lower than a value in the same time.Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

As with any other random number in a range, you can simply add a constant to a random number drawn from a range. For example, if you want to go forward between 10 and 30, then you add 20 to a number in the range 0-10. That would look like:

`forward 20 + random-float 10`